Async batched calls to /search/query endpoint
I'm building a service using our company Sharepoint data that performs the following steps:

ingests a bunch of names of PDFs as a list of strings

runs a sequence of get requests to the Sharepoint API endpoint
{baseSpUrl}/_api/search/query?querytext='title:{queryString}'

runs a sequence of post requests to the SP.MoveCopyUtil.FileByPath() Sharepoint API endpoint, to move each successfully found PDF to a generated folder in another specified location.


I've successfully built a synchronous version of this service. However, the list of PDFs to find can get long-ish (on the order of 50-100 PDFs to search every time the service is run), so I want to script up a version that performs the last two steps in async batches.
At the moment I'm using the aiohttp and asyncio packages in python to try to achieve this. The final step (moving the files) seems to nicely support larger asynchronous calls, but I'm running into a new problem when I try to perform the search queries asynchronously. I get the following message frequently:
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "This query could not be completed because the system is running low on resources."
        }
    }
}

Even with a modest testing set of 5 distinct PDF names, about 1 or 2 of them will consistently crap out like this (and which exact ones fail, typically changes from run to run).
I haven't seen this message before, so I'm looking for advice on handling this step.
Is this just an inherent resource throttling feature for this endpoint because search queries are expensive?
Are there more suitable endpoints for step 2?
For context, the company Sharepoint site contains tens of thousands of files and the PDFs are stored in irregular locations throughout-- this influenced my original decision to use the search endpoint in the synchronous version.
